# Appending the contents of variable to a text file within html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a list of users including all their data as each is added to a website.  This includes login, password, first name last name and the time their entry is created.

The location inside the html file where this is done already has a separate function assigned and everything works except there is no text file created. 
'
I tried to add this with a separate php section using '`file_put_contents ($file, $var1, Var2 )`etc.'  with the '`file_append` flag' set.  While I got no errors when running,  I also got no file.  And yes, i have full read/write permissions in that folder

I have been told jQuery might work but I have no idea how to accomplish that.
All the information is gathered into 5 variables.  I need the simplest way to append these as created in a single line entry of a text file `(Userlist.txt)` that can store the information for all users as they are added.

`document.getElementById('username').value = username;`                                     `document.getElementById('password').value = password;`                                          `document.getElementById('confirm').value = password;`

This is the PHP I tried to use
`<?php`
`$file = 'people.txt';`
`($file, $timeValue $first_name $username $password, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`
`?>`

```
    '$file = 'cache/newfile.txt';
      if(usernameLength == 0){
        var first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        var last_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
        var composed = first_name+last_name;
        var fullHash = CryptoJS.MD5(composed).toString();       
        var username = fullHash.substr(0,8);
        var password = fullHash.substr(fullHash.length - 8);
        document.getElementById('username').value = username;
        document.getElementById('password').value = password;
        document.getElementById('confirm').value = password     
        $date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s'); 
        $output =  $date . "\t" . $first_name . "\t" . $last_name . "\t" . $password;

        file_put_contents($file, $output, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);>
```

I tried the edits as suggested inside the html and I admit I am not sure about what I am doing.  What happens is that the whole function fails when activated.  no errors, but no file is created and the input stops.
Thanks

Comment: Are your permissions correct in the folder you are trying to create the file in?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, for example, your script is stored in the "public_html" folder and you want your output saving into the "public_html/secure" folder.

You'll want to:

1. Save all of your variables into one string
2. Save this string into your output file

Try this:

```
<?php

  //Define where the output will be saved
  $file = 'secure/file.txt';

  //Define your Timezone if not already explicitly defined in your php.ini
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

  //Store your variables in a string, separated by a tab (\t)
  $date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s'); //Gets the date in format 31/01/2016 12:59:59
  $output =  $date . "\t" . $var1 . "\t" . $var2 . "\t" . $var3;

  file_put_contents($file, $output, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

To explore some more, search for the functions you want to customise or learn some more about on http://www.php.net/

If you're still having trouble, please post your code and a little more info on where your files are saved and I'll be happy to have a look.
: )

Comment: The last person assisting me tried to move the whole thing to the concurrent php module.  The problem is that the entered password is modified before getting there and the resulting values were not as needed.  If the writing can be done immediately after the values are entered while in the html section they would all be correct in every way.